# Finding a $2\times 2$ matrix $A\ne 0$ to satisfy $e^{2\pi A} = I$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Just like the title says, I want to find a $2\times 2$ matrix that satisfies the above equation. I have the matrix exponential expansion i.e. $$e^{tA} = I + tA + {\frac{t^2}2}A^2 + ...$$ then I'm plugging in my given value of $t=2\pi$, but I can't figure out a solution to this problem.  I can't see when a scalar ($2 \pi$) multiplied into a matrix would give me zero terms in my series?  I thought then that the terms should have to alternate sign, but I can't seem to come up with a matrix that will allow me to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $A=\lambda I$ is a scalar matrix, then $e^{tA}=e^{t\lambda}I$. Therefore if $A=\begin{bmatrix}i&0\\0&i\end{bmatrix}$, then $e^{2\pi A}=I$.

A more interesting question is finding a real $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ with $e^{2\pi A}=I$. One example is 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

$e^{2\pi A}$ can be computed in this case by diagonalizing $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$.